# Exception is not being thrown, inside task.ContinueWith(), even when .Result is used

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

**When running below program, I am getting output as
But when I use getTask.Result outside continueWith, I am seeing exception instantly.
I am following a pluralsight course, Instructor is getting exception,  but it's behaving differently for me.**

```
Going to start work
Setting up continuation
Continuing with main method
Press any key to continue . . .



static void Main(string[] args)
{            
  var web = new WebClient();            
  Console.WriteLine( "Going to start work");
  //slowmissing has a process request where statuscode is set to 404
  Task<string> getTask=  web.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://localhost:49182/SlowMissing.ashx");
   Console.WriteLine(  "Setting up continuation");
   getTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
   { 
      Console.WriteLine(t.Result); 
   });
   Console.WriteLine( "Continuing with main method");
   Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am getting same op with Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            string result =
            web.DownloadString("http://localhost:49182/SlowMissing.ashx");
            Console.WriteLine("In the Task");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);return result;
        });

Comment: @HansPassant maybe you are not aware that almost all tasks are created hot and do not need to be started. In particular, await, Result and Wait never start anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, `t.Result` throws. This causes the continuation task to exit in a faulted state. This happens before there is console output.

Maybe you want:

```
Console.WriteLine(t.Status);
Console.WriteLine(t.Exception);
```

Also, the program is racy due to the 10 seconds delay. I assume you are aware of that and have made sure that the URL responds in less time... If not, wait for the continuation task to complete e.g. `Task.WhenAll(continuationTask).Wait()`.

Comment: Thanks, I did tried t.status, t.exception they are able to output exception information, but I am not able to understand why t.Result() is not throwing an exception. URL responds spontaneously.

Comment: t.Result throws. I have explained to you why you are not seeing that. Do you not understand the explanation? Wrap `t.Result` in a try catch to print the exception.

Comment: I handled it using if(IsFaulted),,I understood now what you meant by"This causes the continuation task to exit in a faulted state", thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regular exceptions are not caught when they occur inside a task. You need to use `AggregateException` to catch exceptions occuring inside tasks.

Encapsulating your code in this should catch it and make you able to see what's wrong:

```
try {
    // Your code here
} catch (AggregateException ex) {
    // The actual exception is included in ex.InnerException
}
```

[You can read more about it on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I did know how to catch AggregateException, but is it like exceptions are not thrown inside tasks, even when I use property like Result or methods like Wait